# How do I (un)comment lines in a ruby file using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way how I can

- comment (add # at the beginning of the line) and
- uncomment remove # from somewhere before the code

on the line(s) when coding in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **Toggle** a block comment (e.g. in Ruby, `#`), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Other comment related commands can be found under `Edit > Comment/Uncomment`.

[image: comment]

Comment: Great, thank you. I tried to google it but didn't find anything.

Comment: I wasn't able to so. I had to wait for 5 mins and left the office then. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Is the comment character based on the langueare ruby,php I am just editing?

Comment: @Radek Yes. Notepad++ uses the comment character defined for a given language.